# Is using a helper method in a model possible and, more importantly, appropriate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

So I have the following line of code in a html.erb:

```
 <%= "Last seen #{distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now.localtime, member.last_sign_in_at.localtime, true, :highest_measure_only => true)} ago" %>
```

And I'd like to simplify it with something like:

```
<%= member.last_seen %>
```

Without thinking much I tried to write an instance method for the class Member like this:

```
  def last_seen
    if last_sign_in_at.nil?
      "User hasn't signed in yet"
    else
      "Last seen #{distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now.localtime, self.last_sign_in_at.localtime, true, :highest_measure_only => true)} ago"
    end
  end
```

It doesn't work, however, since I can't access the helper method: `distance_of_time_in_words` in the Models.

What'd be the appropriate way to make `<%= member.last_seen %>` work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models aren't the appropriate place to put presentation logic, which is what this is. This is what helper methods are for. A good rule of thumb is if it's not raw data coming out of a model, you're mixing presentation with domain.

It would be more appropriate to do something like:

```
# app/helpers/member_helper.rb

module MemberHelper   
  def last_seen(member)
    if member.last_sign_in_at.nil?
      "User hasn't signed in yet"
    else
      "Last seen #{distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now.localtime, member.last_sign_in_at.localtime, true, :highest_measure_only => true)} ago"
    end
  end
end
```

But to be honest, unless you're using something like this on a ton of pages in varying contexts, moving this code to a helper may be overkill vs leaving it in the view.

Comment: Ok Gavin thanks. It make sense and that was my other option I was hoping there could be a way to call it as if was an instance method, but it's not that bad. Thanks a lot